# drawing vertical and diagonal lines in PIL

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

im trying to generate are some equal vertical and diagonal lines in PIL. I already have horizontal lines but i cant get vertical and diagonal. [image]

**Code for horizontal**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random

im = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
colors = [(255,0,0), (255,255,0), (255,0,255)]
random.shuffle(colors)
n = 0
length = len(colors)
amount = 1000 / length
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 0
y2 = 1000
for color in colors:
    shape = [(x1+ amount, y1  // 2), (x2+ amount, y2  // 2)]
    draw.line(shape, fill=color, width=int(amount))
    x1 += amount
    x2 += amount

im.save('rect.png')
```

Comment: Please put the code in your question that is **not** working.

Comment: @martineau i have changed to what i had for vertical

Comment: Your code for vertical works for me.

Comment: @martineau i have added what im getting

Comment: Wat is wrong with it exactly?

Comment: it isnt full, you can see white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw the vertical lines filling the image, you need to position the endpoints of one line once for each of the color it will be drawn in. The initial X position of start and end points of the first line is ½ the line's width to the right of origin in the upper left of the image. The Y coordinates are 0 and image's height.

Code that does this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random

IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = 1000, 1000

img = Image.new('RGB', (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
colors = [(255,0,0), (255,255,0), (255,0,255)]
random.shuffle(colors)

length = len(colors)
amount = IMG_WIDTH / length
offset = amount / 2  # 1/2 line width
x1, y1 = offset, 0
x2, y2 = offset, IMG_HEIGHT

for color in colors:
    endpoints = (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
    draw.line(endpoints, fill=color, width=int(amount))
    x1 += amount
    x2 += amount

img.save('rect.png')
#img.show()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I just rotated my horizontal image:

```py
colorimage = Image.open('horizontal.png')
out = colorimage.rotate(90)
out.save('vertical.png')
```